# Redirect a page to a different web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, google-chrome, intranet

I have a ASP.Net page for our company and we are running a parallel testing to the new web site. Now, the I attached a clickable image on the old website which redirects to the new web site.

My problem is the old website can be browsed in any web browser while the new web site must only be opened using a specific web browser (due to the developers of the new web site said that it only works properly on google chrome).

All I need is when when they browse the old web site using whatever browser they have, and then click the image, it will open the new website using google chrome.

These web sites are published on the company's windows server, and all clients that connects to it has google chrome installed with them.

If there is something like:
*System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", <url>);*
that will be executed on the client side (not on the server side), kindly advise.

Comment: You can check this question to use an ActiveX client
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057576/launch-application-from-a-browser

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible unless you have some client software that can receive a call from the website to launch Chrome. My answer can be backed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946976/how-can-i-redirect-to-ie-from-other-browsers) question about IE redirection to other browser. The accepted answer is absolutely correct.

The security risk would be too great and besides windows doesn't support that kind of linking. You could write a "client" program that runs in the background waiting for a call from your website. Then the client program could launch Chrome.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Can I humbly ask you to specify some client software that can help answer the OP's concerns?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona Sorry, I meant he would need to write one. I edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is it your problem ? : you want to open your link via Google chrome .
if yes , you cant do it !
because ASP.net , PHP and etc .. a server side language and cant do it ! , its not possible without have any application on clients .