# Cross browser session in web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay, session-cookies, session-management

I have web application ( liferay based ) logged in to Firefox also I have another legacy application which runs only on IE. Is there any way I can redirect user from Firefox to IE after logging in to firefox, providing link to redirect user to IE in same session without asking for login to application in IE.

Comment: Not that I know of. A session is related to a client and a different browser means a different client. Also, you can't open specific programs in the client machine. You can only point to a document the client decides which program to use to open it with.

Comment: you should check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946976/how-can-i-redirect-to-ie-from-other-browsers

Comment: thanks @MarcCompte I have read about localstorage instead of session storage. Would that represent a security threat ..?

Comment: thanks @SagarR for reference

Comment: @ravipachar : does it help you ?

Comment: @SagarR as per thread I should make application compatible with all browser or force user to use only IE. This stands true & last option as well. But I'm just exploring other ways If I can get any reliable & secure way of doing this.

Comment: @ravipachar : there was one answer which was suggesting by using javascript you can do that,you can also try that suggestion,if it works than also share with us.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No , session is browser specific, so two different browsers cannot have the same session.